# numpy arctan funtion mirrored angle

Tags: python, numpy

Problem: there is a coordinate grid of points of data, they need to be filtered to a specific, curved area.

Solution:

- How is the area determined?

  - Within a grid, you are given a specific point (A) on that grid & an 
    angle from that point (determined in relation to the grid)
  - You are also given a target point (B) within the grid
  - Draw 2 circles of differing, specific radii from point (A)
  - Mark an area bounded by 45 degrees from either side of the given angle
  - Evaluate each point on the grid to see if it falls within the area bounded by the 2 circles and the 90-degree section

Issue with my solution: rather than filtering 1 area, 2 mirrored areas are filtered, allowing for incorrect data.

each point on the grid is evaluated by the function below if it fits within the filtered area. I've looked into the arctan2 function to see if it will help, but don't understand it. A full summary of the issue can be found [here](http://coiro.co.uk/math_summary.docx)

here are some clarifying images:

[What this should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDFPH.jpg),[what this code looks like in practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Cg7.png),as well as [some testable data](http://www.coiro.co.uk%5Ctestgrilla.csv)

```
def pertenece(x,y,x_pala,y_pala,alpha):
    #parametros R int y R ext
    R_int = 17
    R_ext = 25
    #def thetas
    Theta_min = (alpha - 45)*(180/m.pi)**-1
    Theta_max = (alpha + 45)*(180/m.pi)**-1

    #calc R punto y Theta punto
    R_punto = ((x-x_pala)**2 + (y-y_pala)**2)**0.5
    Theta_punto = np.arctan((y-y_pala)/(x-x_pala))

    if (R_punto >= R_int and R_punto<=R_ext) and (Theta_punto >= Theta_min and Theta_punto<=Theta_max):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

as can be seen in the document there should be only one quadrant filtered out, in practice there are 2.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful to attach an image here. And some sample data to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed be using `np.arctan2` because otherwise it can't differentiate between differently signed input. For example `np.arctan(1 / 2)` is the same as `np.arctan(-1 / -2)` because the argument is the same. For that reasons you'll preserve both the `(-,-)` and the `(+,+)` quadrant. For `np.arctan2` you simply pass both coordinates as separate arguments so the algorithm can figure out the quadrant from the sign of the two arguments. Hence you should compute the following:

```
Theta_punto = np.arctan2((y-y_pala), (x-x_pala))
```

Comment: thanks, this clarification was exactly what I was looking for!, it solved my problem perfectly

Comment: @noble_gasses If it solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer so the question is marked accordingly.